# Getting a Starting Row with e.range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, timestamp

I'm using a script on *Google Sheets* that makes a timestamp on a cell when the value of the cell next to it is set. It clears the date if the value of the cell next to it is deleted.

However, it's affecting the entire sheet. **I only want this code to function starting at row 18.**

I'm very new to coding. I've done some research but still can't figure it out. I have a variable defined called *StartRow* and tried using that in my *if statement* and then my *loop* instead of *"e.range.rowStart"* but it triggered the date several times upward.

Can someone please give me feedback on what I may need to change or add? Thanks in advance!

Here's the code I'm using:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = ["Sheet1"];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var StartRow = 18; //(defined but not sure where or if I should use it)
  var InputCol = 6;
  var OutputCol = 7;

  if (sheet.indexOf(ss.getName()) == -1 || e.range.columnStart != InputCol) return;

  var val = ss.getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart).getValue();
  if (val) {
    var date = new Date();
    for (var i = e.range.rowStart; i <= e.range.getLastRow(); i++)
      ss.getRange(i, OutputCol).setValue(date);
  } else
    ss.getRange(e.range.rowStart, OutputCol, e.range.getLastRow() - e.range.rowStart + 1).clearContent();
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you want the function to do.  It's difficult to figure out what you wish from your code.

Comment: I'll provide a link to an example of my form. When a word is added to a cell in column 6 (Assigned), a date stamp is automatically added to a cell in column 7 (Date). When the word is deleted, the date stamp also clears. I only want this to occur with cells below row 18. For example, I have a header. When I make changes to the header (Column F), it adds a date (Column G), which I do not want. I only want it to function at and after row 18, not above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet1' && e.range.rowStart > 18 && e.range.columnStart == 6) {
    if (e.value) {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(new Date());
    } else {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue('');
    }
  }
}
```